# IIS authorization for use in a non asp site

Tags: authentication, iis, iis-7, web-config

I have a single IIS server that runs many web sites all with their own IP addresses.  These sites are all ASP sites.  I have a new site I need to add that was done in straight HTML and is not an ASP site.  The request is to only allow people into the site who have been authenticated to one of the other sites.  I am using IIS 7 on Windows 2008 Server R2.

Not sure if that's possible, but here's what I did so far:

Added the following to system.webServer:

```
<modules>
  <add name="FormsAuthenticationModule" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
  <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />
  <remove name="DefaultAuthentication" />
  <add name="DefaultAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule" />
</modules>
```

Added the following to system.web:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
<authentication mode="Forms" />
```

Tried adding the following to system.web as well:

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides setting the authentication mode to Windows which I missed at first, other steps to do this are:

- Open IIS, and make sure an application pool exists for the site.
- Set it's mode to integrated.
- Open the site itself in IIS
- In the IIS section open Authentication.
- Enable Windows Authentication.
- Modify the web.config adding users/groups as needed to the authorization
  section.
- Here's one thing I didn't realize - it doesn't process all rules and overwrite previous rules with new rules.  It stops once it finds a rule that works.  So you don't deny all users, then add one. You add the one you want, then deny all after.
- The system.webServer section from the OP is correct.